# parse string of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

How do I parse string of array so i can get the value of variable

sample string

```
$str = 'prices[holiday:waterpark][person:1_person]';
```

sample variable

```
$prices['holiday:waterpark']['person:1_person'] = 100;
```

I have tried using variables.variable way in php like this

```
$prices['holiday:waterpark']['person:1_person'] = 100;
$str = "prices\['holiday:waterpark'\]\['person:1_person'\]";
$str = str_replace('\\', '', $str);
echo $$str;
```

but thats not working and I get an error

```
"Undefined variable: $prices['holiday:waterpark']['person:1_person']"
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: your post is confusing. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry i don't know how to explain it any better. Basically i need to parse string to variable so i can get the value of variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?
    $prices['holiday:waterpark']['person:1_person'] = 100;
    $str = "prices\['holiday:waterpark'\]\['person:1_person'\]";
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    // be careful with passing $str from untrusted source
    // make necessary variable filtering before!
    echo eval('return $' . $str . ';');
```